# Integrate Azure AD with AngularJS and call CORS web api

Tags: angularjs, azure, active-directory, adal.js

After going through the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-angularjs-spa, we have created a web application named ToDoSpa and web api named ToGoApi registered in Azure Active Directory and are able to authenticate but the problem lies in consuming the web api including the endpoints as

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '2528e8f3' named 'ToDoSpa '. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
>   Trace ID: df70a02e-6a53-4899-8319-0ba440540500
>   Correlation ID: 699515a6-dccb-421e-92ae-e9b5a700ad1b
>   Timestamp: |interaction_required".
>
> Client Id:
>   ToDoSpa->2528e8f3
>   ToGoApi->815933a4

In ToDoSpa,we have defined the scopes for the application ToDoSpa as "User.Read and Directory.Read.All" and authorized the client application using the client ID of web api(815933a4) in Expose API. In App permission, we have included ToDoSpa and have grant consent the application.

app.js

```
var endpoints = {
"https://graph.microsoft.com": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
"https://localhost:44392/api/weather": "https://firstupconsultants.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoApi"<!--localhost:App Id Uri of Server-->
};
adalProvider.init({
instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
tenant: '<tenant-id>',
clientId: '<client-id of server>',
endpoints: endpoints,
extraQueryParameter: 'prompt=admin_consent'
}, $httpProvider);
}]);

 //Get
weather1.getWeather = function () {
return $http.get("https://localhost:44392/api/weather").then(succeessCallback, failedCallback);

function succeessCallback(weather) {
    //$scope.weather = weather.data;    
    weather1.items = weather.data;
}

function failedCallback(error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred:", error);
}
}
```

web.config

```
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="<tenant-id>"/>
<add key="ida:Audience" value="https://firstupconsultants.onmicrosoft.com/ToGoApi"/>
<!--localhost:App Id Uri of Server-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when you build an application that uses application permissions, the app requires a page or view on which the admin approves the app's permissions. This page can be part of the app's sign-in flow, part of the app's settings, or it can be a dedicated "connect" flow.

When you're ready to request permissions from the organization's admin, you can redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform admin consent endpoint.

Here is sample URL for the same:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

When you want to enable the users on other tenant can use the application, the application required to give the consent first. To do that you can make a HTTP request to grant the admin consent easily by using the prompt parameter.

You can read about this in detail in below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin

Additional reference:

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/

Hope it helps.